# How to disable gedit side panel?

Tags: gnome, gedit, panel

How do i disable this stupid side panel of gedit, that somehow appeared?
There is nothing in the settings or plugins.
Tried rm -r -f ~/.config/gedit as well, with no success.
I don't have big screen and i find it totally useless and eating up what little free space for editing documents i have.

See Screenshot

[image: see screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Settings --> View, uncheck "Side Panel"

[image]

...Or use the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

Comment: Or press `F9`. Operates the side panel in the same fashion as the checkbox (only easier to access), and the choice is remembered even after closing / reopening the app.

Comment: Thank You! You helped me a lot today.